# Goroutine cancellation with recovery

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine, channel, go-context

Without frameworks like RxGo, how could I accomplish the following in Go?:

- Three goroutines of different running times are in a context: short, medium, and, long. These goroutines are long-running jobs like reading or uploading a large file.
- If any one of the three goroutines cancel (on error), the other two will cancel.
- Run code on all three goroutines when cancelled (like panic & recover). These are actions like, closing the large file or notifying the upload has failed.

In a diagram, the desired outcome:

[image]

Updated attempt:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func randInt(min int, max int) int {
    return min + rand.Intn(max-min)
}

func main() {

    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    errworker := make(chan int, 4)

    work := func(i int, ec chan int, c context.Context, cx context.CancelFunc) {
        defer wg.Done()

        workchan := make(chan struct{})

        go func() {
            interval := time.Duration(randInt(1, 10000)) * time.Millisecond
            fmt.Printf("Operation %d started: will take %s\n", i, interval)
            time.Sleep(interval)

            if randInt(0, 100) > 80 {
                fmt.Printf("Operation %d failed!\n", i)
                ec <- i
                cx()
            }
            workchan <- struct{}{}
        }()

        select {
        case <-workchan:
            fmt.Printf("Operation %d done\n", i)
        case <-c.Done():
            fmt.Printf("Operation %d halted\n", i)
        }
    }

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go work(i, errworker, ctx, cancel)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(errworker)
    for e := range errworker {
        fmt.Printf("Error in worker %d\n", e)
    }
}
```

(Edit) Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/CNACYe43Dh3

Updated attempt playground: https://go.dev/play/p/5lzdERwqG8o

Is there a simple, elegant ELI5 solution to this problem? I can't help but notice with channels, I may need child contexts with child goroutines to listen for the cancellation signal, since when a goroutine enters a long running job, there was no way (from what I've tried) to stop the goroutine other than cancelling the context altogether. A controlled way to terminate the goroutines early is desired.

**(Edit)**
In my updated attempt I simply placed the actual work in an inner goroutine while the outer goroutine listens for context completion. In this attempt I decided to use an error channel (although in theory only one error will come through) to catch and process errors at the end.

Are there any caveats or blind spots to this approach? Feel free to correct me on implementation and approach, the goal is to have a controlled way to terminate goroutines early.

Thanks!

Comment: A "broadcast" cancel is usually achieved by having a channel that you simply `close` to cancel. Anyone who needs to check for this tests "can I read from the channel". Since the only time you get a "yes" answer is when it has been closed, that's your signal to finish up and quit. And, since closing the channel happens just once and causes everyone with read access to it to see that it's readable from then on, it works great as a broadcast.

Comment: " goroutines are long-running jobs like reading or uploading a large file" if your long running operations support a context, you can use that to cancel. Unfortunately many file operations do not support a context, thus you can't interrupt them while they're running, so you cant' abort early.